# Is there a string table resource for Visual C# 2005?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, localization

As a developer who spent many years working within Visual C++ 6, I'm used to working with the String Table resource to store unicode strings for localization. Is there a resource within Visual Studio 2005 that provides the same? Are there any third party libraries or tools?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[ResourceManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.resources.resourcemanager) is your friend - and yes, Visual Studio still has support for it all in the editor. You might also want to read "[Encoding and Localization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/globalization-localization)". If you're really keen, I can thoroughly recommend [Guy Smith-Ferrier's book on .NET i18n](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321341384).

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is "resources.resx" -- if you used a template for your new project, you probably have one already.  Open it up, then drop down the "resource type" picker and select Strings.  You can access them as (project namespace).Properties.Resources.(string name), though you may need to prepend a "global::" to that.

Of course, as Jon points out, for multi-language localization, you can access multiple resource files independently.